# BASH: Find maximum value in repeating groups

Tags: bash, sorting, csv, awk, grep

I have the following csv file `file1.csv`

```
sales,artist
10,0131
10,0131
10,10_000 Maniacs
10,1000names
15,E1001 Ways
15,E1001 Ways
10,S101 Strings Orchestra
10,D101 Strings Orchestra
10,x0cc
10,x0cc
```

I am writing a BASH command to find the total sales for every artist. The output is sorted by total sales value in descending order.

```
Expected output.

30,E1001 Ways
20,0131
20,x0cc
10,10_000 Maniacs
10,1000names   
10,S101 Strings Orchestra
10,D101 Strings Orchestra
```

I have written the code to find the maximum value but it gives me maximum sales values for all artists and not the total sales maximum for every artist.

```
 sort -nr file1.csv | awk 'BEGIN { FS="," }{ print $2; }'
```

Any help to solve this?
Thanks.

Output

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { sales[$9] += $3 } END { for(s in sales) print sales[s] FS s }' million_songs_metadata_and_sales.csv | sort -nr -k1 | head -10

903,10000 Maniacs
562,51717
513,12012
506,35007
350,37500 Yens
2788,7000 Dying Rats
2325,2002
2210,1001 Ways
1992,1349
1968,1200 Techniques
```

Comment: if it is sorted that way pipe it to `awk` and select/print the first entry when the id  E1001,0131 and so on changes. hope this helps. regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { sales[$2] += $1 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"; for(s in sales) print sales[s] FS s }' file1.csv
```

That is

```
NR > 1 {                 # from the second line onwards (to skip the header)
  sales[$2] += $1        # sum up the totals
}
END {                    # and in the end

  # GNU-specific: array traversal in numerically descending order of value
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"

  for(s in sales) {      # print the lot.
    print sales[s] FS s
  }
}
```

With plain awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { sales[$2] += $1 } END { for(s in sales) print sales[s] FS s }' file1.csv | sort -nr
```

that is, remove the GNU-specific `PROCINFO` bit and pipe the result through `sort -nr`.

Comment: I need to find the total sales for every artist. I guess what you are finding is the maximum sale value for every artist.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Easy fix, though -- the code even becomes simpler. See edit.

Comment: Thanks! The values are right but for some reason the sorted order is not strictly descending. I am using plain awk.

Comment: Hm. The `sort -nr` should take care of that, and does for me. Are you using the GNU coreutils, or does your `sort` perhaps work differently?

Comment: I have updated the question to show you the output I am seeing.

Comment: Yeah, your `sort` works differently, which is odd given that it accepts the `-n` option. It appears to do a lexicographical instead of a numeric sort (that's why everything beginning with 9 comes at the top). If I pipe that output through my `sort -nr`, I get the expected output. If you run `sort --version`, does it tell you what sort it is? Or: what operating system do you use? Mac OS X? In that case, try without the `-k1` (hoping I read the manpage correctly).

Comment: I am running sort (GNU coreutils) 8.13. I tried with '-nr' and '-n -k1 -r' both give me the same output. I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you recommend any other method to avoid the sort issue? I am looking online and it is a strange error.

Comment: Hmm...I'm on Debian with coreutils 8.23 and it works flawlessly. An easy way to avoid the whole thing would be doing `sudo apt-get install gawk` and using the GNU awk method.

Comment: It gives me the same result with GNU awk. This is strange.

Comment: Huh. That should definitely not happen. I'll meditate on it. EDIT: What locale are you using? Does it work if you run `LC_ALL=C awk` with the GNU solution? EDIT2: Although that shouldn't make a difference inside awk. Hm. If you use the generic awk solution and pipe through `LC_ALL sort -rn`, what does it do then?